# ListView adapter, dynamic row height and bad behaviour

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

Don't know if anyone has run into this issue and I'm not sure there is a solution to this. I have a listview with a complex adapter bound to it. Each row can be different from each others. There could be only text, or an image, or an image + text. Just like Facebook Timeline for example. I have 3-4 types of view that can be inflated (it depends on the type of item). The main problem is the one with image + text. This is the view item row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/post_picture"/>
        <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/loading_bar"/>
            </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:maxLines="8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/post_message"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I put no source inside the ImageView, so when it's time to rendering, Android set the cell height as if there is no image. On the getView method of the adapter, I load an image inside the ImageView (I use ion, but I tried with UrlImageViewHelper also, with no results). When the image is loaded and rendered the row height expands to fit all the content (I've wrap_content set on the layout).

This is the problem: When I scroll down, there are no problems. When I scroll up, and Android has removed the image from memory, it loads the empty row. When the image is reloaded and rendered, the row height expands and it pushes down all the rows that are below. For example, if I load a 200x1080 image, the effect is really bad!

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Try to layout your imageView with the dummy image and then set the visibility of the ImageView to View.GONE! And if you have to load one row with the image, just set the visibility to View.VISIBLE

Comment: Yes I've thought about something like this. The problem is that I don't know the dimension of the image that I'm going to load. Could be 50x50 to 720x720

Comment: Is the image you are loading a bitmap? Or you just loading from a res Drawable folder?

Comment: Bitmaps from the web. I use their urls to load them into the imageview